# ImportError: cannot import name 'HttpResponce' from 'django.http'

Tags: python, django

So, I'm trying to create a web, and I use django. My code is next:

```
from django.http import HttpResponce

def index(request):
    return HttpResponce('Hello World!!!')
```

I don't understand why it workes in another projects and doesn't work now.

Comment: Look closely at the spelling you used. It's spelled `HttpResponse`, with an `se` at the end, not `ce`.

Answer (score 3):

You misspelled `response` as `responce`